# tikz-timing package gives up on path after 25 clock cycles

Tags: errors, tikz-timing

I'm using the `tikz-timing` package to do some timing diagrams, but it seems that it has an upper limit of 25 clock cycles.

While

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikztimingtable}
 clk          &  50{C} \\
 temp &   25{HL}  \\
\end{tikztimingtable}%
\end{document}
```

works just fine, but if I change to

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikztimingtable}
 clk          &  51{C} \\
 temp &   25{HL}  \\
\end{tikztimingtable}%
\end{document}
```

I get a "giving up on this path. did you forget a semicolon?" error.
Anybody know how to do longer timing diagrams?

Comment: Both compiles fine in my machine with `TL2012, tikz-timing v0.7d`

Comment: Both examples works fine for me in a current miktex 2.9.

Comment: thats odd. i use V0.7 also.
but i get the error, i think my example is as simple as it gets.
Im using pdf2latex

Comment: btw im using kile

Comment: @Rasmus just to be sure, hpesoj626 was talking about the revision 'd' of the version 0.7 of the package. Do you really have the same revision index (you just write V0.7 without other precision)?

Comment: how do i check the actual version?

Comment: ok i found out that im not using the same.. only my documentation was o.7 im actually using 0.6a
i tried to update. but in the log its still the old file.
do i need to locate and delete the old sty files?
i used this guide to install the new package
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LaTeX

Comment: @Rasmus I'm using also Linux (Fedora) and I find that using a complete installation of Texlive is far easier than the Fedora's old package. Following this http://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html I have all installed under `/opt/texlive` so that it won't be conflicting with the Fedora's packaging system. The updating of the Texlive distrib is done with their tool.

Comment: i found out how to update. thank you and it solved my problems.
i will try to install the texlive and test that

Comment: @Rasmus: Please consider to accept my answer, so that this thread gets marked as completed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the author of `tikz-timing`. This error happens when TikZ, which is internally used by `tikz-timing`, has to expand too many macros before finding the semicolon. The maximal number of macro expansions got reduced with PGF/TikZ v2.00 which causes trouble with `tikz-timing` which needs sometimes a lot of expansions, especially for longer signals (even if these can be written quite short).

To overcome this issue I changed `tikz-timing` in v0.7b to locally increase the maximum numbers of macro expansions inside the internal TikZ command to the original used value. Therefore an package update should fix this issue as already stated in the comments by others.

As a workaround you can ensure that the internal TikZ path is never too long by adding `;` into your `tikz-timing` line. This characters closes the internal TikZ-path at this point (like `;` does in TikZ).
So, try `50{C};50{C}` instead of `100{C}` for example.